# Updating a particular div using jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application. I am trying to delete some data from database. I use ajax to pass data, and Upon deletion it returns success. Now I just want to refresh only that particular div. I don't want to refresh the whole page. Is it possible?

Comment: yes. but what do you want it to show, just a success message? documentation for $.append() or $.html() is your friend. http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: You have to fetch that data again by ajax and set to the div.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function removeHistory(id) {
  $.ajax({
   url : "/removeHistory?id=" + id,
   type : 'POST',
   dataType : 'html',
   data : {
   },
   success : function() {
    // code to update div
   }
  });
 }
</script>

Here id is the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following links:

1. [Refreshing a DIV after form submission in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243864/2123679)
2. [How to update a 'div' content after that ActiveRecord values are changed without reload the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4676774/2123679)
3. [Refresh a div without reloading the page](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4414644)
4. [Update only div panel on button click in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861908/2123679)

Hope these links will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry all your links doesn't satisfy my requirements. I don't want to update a div. I just want to reload the contents again.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you like

https://github.com/chrismccord/sync